# Flask-Security force SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW to use HTTPS

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-security

I've run into an issue where the post-login redirect in Flask-Security is not keeping to HTTPS and is instead making an HTTP request. In some instances this is causing an error.
Ideally my nginx config would redirect all requests on :80 to :443 automatically, but apparently this is problematic as well. While I sort out the nginx issue I would really like to force Flask Security to always use HTTPS.

My current var for this is just:
`SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW = '/logged-in'`

The [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html) says an endpoint name can be used as well, but it does not say what the format for that is. Do you just provide the endpoint name or is it wrapped in a `url_for()`?

Is there a way to force Flask Security to always use HTTPS, either in this particular instance or as a whole?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before. In fact, because of this limitation. I started to use flask-jwt instead of flask-security. Here is the link to the project https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer about Flask-Security itself, but you can force all HTTP traffic to redirect to HTTPS with Google's [Flask-Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman). That will fix the problem no matter what library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

An old but important questions.  I spent too much time working through this but here goes:

The answer is that Flask's url_for() is returning a relative url such as '/logged-in'.

werkzeug by default (via its autocorrect_location_header = True Response option) creates a fully qualified URL.

Where does it get the scheme and server?
It gets it by calling wsgi.get_current_url() -

which for scheme uses: environ["wsgi.url_scheme”]

Assuming you are using uwsgi https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - it seems to look at the variables
UWSGI_SCHEME and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and if neither are set then look at the variable HTTPS, else set wsgi.url_scheme=“http”

Most examples of setting up uwsgi+python say to place this (and others) in your
uwsgi_params file that is included in your nginx config:

```
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
```

I believe that simply setting:

```
uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME https;
```

in your nginx config would force flask to believe the request was https regardless.

I use AWS ALB which seems to set all the relevant X-FORWARDED-xxx headers so
things just work.

If you need to handle both http and https and your LB doesn’t set
the headers - then the werkzeug folks have an answer - https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint name is the name of the view function.
Basically, if your desired route is decorating the `show_home` function,

`app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW'] = 'show_home'`

```
@app.route('/your-route')
def show_home():
    ...
```

PS: I am not sure what was the situation when the question was posted, but I describe the situation for `Flask-security-too==4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Flask-Security app.config['SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW'] = '/logged-in' conflicts with the "next" URL (https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/850).

This happens whenever a user is being redirected to satisfy an authentication requirement (@login_required) to access a particular route. The "next" URL takes precedence. You might want to ensure the application landing page does not require authentication.

'SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW' functions properly without **next=%2F**
e.g https://app_url/login?**next=%2F**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).